# How to give Data Annotation Validation for NOT NULL OR ZERO in MVC3 Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

```
     [RegularExpression("", ErrorMessage = " Affordable fees cannot be Zero or Negative.")]
    public decimal AffordablePayment { get; set; }
```

I need a regular expression for ErrorMessage in the DataAnnotation Validation. Please help me out .Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
[Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Affordable fees cannot be Zero or Negative.")]
public decimal AffordablePayment { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$)
```